# Every Sturm-Liouville problem is a Schrödinger equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, sturm-liouville

Imagine the Sturm-Liouville problem
$$
(pu')'+qu+\lambda ru=pu''+p'u'+qu+\lambda ru=0
$$
Let $h=\frac{1}{(pq)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$, $u=hv$. Deriving in the above equation and multiplying by h, we arrive at
$$
h(p(hv''+2h'v'+h''v)+p'(hv'+h'v)+qhv+\lambda rhv)=0
$$
$$
(h^2pv')'+h(ph''+p'h'+qh)v+\lambda r h^2 v=0
$$
Let $\hat{p}=h^2p$, $\hat{q}=h(ph''+p'h'+qh)$, $\hat{r}=rh^2$. Thus $\hat{r}\hat{p}=1$.
Now let $y=\int\frac{1}{\hat{p}(x)}dx = \int\hat{r}(x)dx$. Now, let $w(y)=v(x)$. Thus, $w$ verifies
$$
w''+\frac{\hat{q}}{\hat{p}}w+\lambda v=0
$$
Let $\tilde{q}=\frac{\hat{q}}{\hat{p}}(x(y))$. Thus, equation has the form
$$
w''+\tilde{q}w+\lambda v=0
$$
which is Schrödinger equation.
Anywhere where I can find more about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176041/the-sturm-liouville-equations-the-schrodinger-equation-and-the-wave-equation ?

Comment: Couldn't help editing: the umlaut in Schroedinger's name is _not_ over the last "e", but over the first "o". I don't know how to make "o-umlaut", so I edited it to "oe"... which is a common anglicization. If some else might take a moment to make it an o-umlaut, that would be great. :)

Comment: Given $y''+p_1y'+p_2y=0$, let $y(x)=v(x)e^{-\int^x dx'p_1(x')}$, then the equation for $v$ will be $v''+Qv=0$ with $Q=p_2-\frac{p_1^2}{4}-\frac{p_1'}{2}$